# Why does AdSense's "active view viewable" data differ between the standard report and the active view tab?

Tags: google-adsense, viewability

In my Adsense Report section I have two very different sets of Active View data:

- The first set of Active View data is the "Active View Viewable" column in the standard report Overview.
- The second set of Active View data is the "Active View Viewable" column in the Active Views tab.

Why are these percentages so different?